# tsql: alternative to select subquery in join

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table layout simplified:

table1: pID (pkey), data
table2: rowID (pkey), pID (fkey), data, date

I want to select some rows from table1 joining one row from table2 per pID for the most recent date for that pID.
I currently do this with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.rowID = (SELECT TOP(1) rowID FROM table2 WHERE pID = a.pID ORDER BY date DESC)
```

This way of working is slow, probabaly because it has to do a subquery on each row of table 1. Is there a way to improve performance on this or do it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something on these lines, use the subquery to get the latest based on the date field (grouping by the pID), then join that with the first table, this way the subquery would not have not have to be executed for *each* row of Table1 and will result in better performance:

```
Select *
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN 
   (
    SELECT pID, Max(Date) FROM Table2
    GROUP BY pID
   ) b
ON a.pID = b.pID
```

I have provided the sample SQL for one column using the **group by**, in case you need additional columns, add them to the GROUP BY clause. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is indeed a lot faster. But in table2 there is one column i also need returned so your code would become:
`Select a.pID, a.data, b.data
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN 
   (
    SELECT pID, Max(Date), data FROM Table2
    GROUP BY pID, data
   ) b
ON a.pID = b.pID`

This way we would get multiple values for one pID, i only need the most recent one.

Comment: Glad this helped :-). Yes, you would need to add the additional columns that you would need in your case.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code, and note that i added the order by Date desc to get the most resent data

```
select *
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.pID=b.pID
where b.rowID in(select top(1) from table2 t where t.pID=a.pID order by Date desc)
```

Comment: thank you, indeed i forgot the order by. But in excution time it stays the same.

Comment: in order to increase the performance you need to index your fields, and i forgot to put the rowID in the select ( select top(1) rowID from table2 t...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() function to get a column saying which id of each row in table 2 is the first (As partitioned by the pID, and ordered by the rowDate descending)

Example:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT 
    rowID AS t2RowId, 
    ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY pID ORDER BY rowDate DESC) AS rowNum
  FROM table2 t2
) -- gets the t2RowIds + a column which says which is the latest for each pID
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  table2 t2
  JOIN cte ON t2.rowID = cte.t2RowId AND cte.rowNum = 1
) ON t1.pID = t2.pID
```

This is guaranteed to only return 1 item from table2 per pID, even if multiple items have the same date. You should of course ensure that the date column is indexed in table 2 for quick performance (ideally an index that also covers the PrimaryID of table2)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code below in a similar scenaro (I transcripted it to your example)

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table1 AS a
left outer join (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table2 a
        inner join (
            SELECT a.pID, max(date) as date 
            FROM table2
            WHERE date <= <max_date>
            group by pID
            ) b ON a.pID = b.pID AND a.date = b.date
        ) b ON a.pID = b.pID
) b on a.pID = b.pID
```

The only problem with this aproach is that you have to make sure the date's don't reapet for the pID's

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `row_number()` function and a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by pId order by rowId desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.pId = t2.pId and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is faster and gets the correct results. Thank you

Comment: @jvcoppen . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?  You can accept whatever answer you like, but I much prefer this approach to the currently accepted answer.